# How to restore my deleted songs?

Tags: file-management

I have cut all my songs from my pc and transferred them to my tab via USB cable. They were stored under a file named 'File Manager'. I saw that I didn't need to copy them to the tab's 'Music' folder (or I couldn't) because they were already in there.

Then I deleted a song from the file manager and it automatically got deleted from the music folder. Then I thought, how about adding the songs to a playlist? Maybe then I can clear my file manager,get more space to get other files in there(right?) and my songs will be saved too. But when I deleted most of my songs from the file manager,they got deleted from the playlist too.

I couldn't find any recycle bin in my tab. Some of them were left in the manager and I tried to delete them but now it shows that 'no permission to delete' and they aren't getting removed from there and the music folder.

Why did it happen before then? And how am I gonna restore my songs back? Please help me and correct me if I did any mistakes mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple misconceptions in your "workflow", so let me try to explain them one by one:

- You've copied the ***files*** to your device and placed them into a ***directory***.
- Once that was done, Android's *MediaScanner* found them and added them to its "library"
- I've never heard they are added to the Music *folder*, so that might be something specific here. They were obviously not *duplicated* (that wouldn't make sense), so what you see as "Music folder" (you didn't specify where you checked that) is most likely rather a "***virtual*** folder" / "Library" / "***View***".
- As the second place was not a copy but rather a pointer, that pointer disappeared as well as soon as you deleted the file.
- A "playlist" can be compared to a text-file listing up available music files, it doesn't contain the files themselves. So as you removed the files, their "pointers" were removed here as well.

So much for what has happened. Next point is that Android is not Windows (but rather based on Linux). By default, there is no "recycle bin" (though there are apps available to emulate that). Gone is gone.

For recovery (and recycle bin) you might wish to take a look at:

- my listing of [De-Deletion (Recovering) apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe#group_872)
- [questions tagged `data-recovery`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery)
- our [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info)

I recommend following these links bottom-up ;)

Comment: Thnx Izzy! I sure will follow them.

Comment: If that solved you issue, don't forget to "tick" the check-mark next to the answer to indicate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since Android tab also uses FAT32 or NTFS file system, I think the deleted one just like the file on PC. It is still there.
Therefore, pull out the SD card, scan it with some [recovery tools](https://www.recovery-tool.com/). Things should be done as you lost a file on PC.